# python 2.7 writing "x in set" vs "set.__contains__(x)"

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, set

I've run the following small test in python 2.7.6:

```
s = set(xrange(0, 1000000))
for i in xrange(0, 5000000):
    if s.__contains__(i):
        pass
```

and got the following output for running `time python py.py`:

```
real    0m0.616s
```

then I changed my code to:

```
s = set(xrange(0, 1000000))
for i in xrange(0, 5000000):
    if i in s:
        pass
```

and got run time of `0.467s`. I also got same results for `dict`. My question is "why there is performance difference?", maybe some explanation of how python performs calls of `s.__contains__(i)` and `i in s`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `s.__contains__(i)` you need to do the attribute lookup in Python, as well as make a method call in Python. These are executed as separate bytecodes:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('s.__contains__(i)', '<>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__contains__)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (i)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 POP_TOP             
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

`LOAD_ATTR` loads the `__contains__` attribute, and `CALL_FUNCTION` then executes the method.

Using `i in s` takes just one bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('i in s', '<>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (s)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here `COMPARE_OP` does all the work.

In C, then, looking up the `__contains__` slot (or rather, its C equivalent) and calling it is much faster.

Note that when comparing two approaches in Python, it is much better to use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) rather than the UNIX `time` command; it'll try to eliminate environmental factors and repeat the test for you:

```
>>> import timeit, random
>>> testset = {random.randrange(50000) for _ in xrange(1000)}
>>> tests = [random.randrange(5000) for _ in xrange(500)]
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in tests: i in s',
...               'from __main__ import testset as s, tests',
...               number=100000)
2.5375568866729736
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in tests: s.__contains__(i)',
...               'from __main__ import testset as s, tests',
...               number=100000)
4.208703994750977
```

Using `__contains__` is slower by some distance.

Comment: Your timeit tests are swamped by a factor of ten by the calls to random.randrange().

Comment: @msw: the `random.randrange()` calls *don't vary between tests*. We are comparing relative timings here. You can generate those random numbers up front if you want, but it won't change the outcome.

Comment: [the result is reverse](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/zed/af2b99517838061ec7b9) on my machine

Comment: @msw: okay, eliminating the random calls makes the contrast higher, so I changed that to a pre-generated test list.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I updated the test to use a pre-generated random sequence of numbers to test, the contrast went up a notch. Perhaps your OS blocked on random numbers to wait for entropy and skewed the results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Rerunning the notebook produces the expected result, though [the difference is small (20%)](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/zed/af2b99517838061ec7b9). Could you run [the ipynb-file](https://gist.github.com/zed/af2b99517838061ec7b9/raw/535f2f1ef1e03ba0e4ca5a6400dc70f813d4377c/Time%20Performance%20of%20%60x%20in%20set%60%20vs%20%60set.__contains__(x)%60.ipynb) using [`ipnbdoctest.py`](https://gist.github.com/minrk/2620735) to compare the result apple-to-apple? To install dependencies, run `pip install -U 'ipython[notebook]'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: replied [in your ipynb-file gist](https://gist.github.com/zed/af2b99517838061ec7b9#comment-1292625).

Comment: it is [clear that the difference doesn't disappear even when we run the same code](https://gist.github.com/zed/af2b99517838061ec7b9#comment-1292637)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I use 2.7.8 on Mac OS X, but nothing in the changelog between 2.7.6 and 2.7.8 jumps out at me as a cause.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've tried 2.7.6 and 2.7.8 versions installed by `pythonz` and they produce results similar to yours. Only `/usr/bin/python` differs. If I recompile the Ubuntu package from source (`apt-get -b source python2.7`) then the difference also vanishes. `/usr/bin/python3` doesn't show the special behaviour.